# Specify a single Payara application to use HTTPS

Tags: https, payara

I am currently using Payara 5 with Apache in front of it to add HTTPS security and perform a few extra rules. I've been asked to see if it's possible to get rid of Apache and just use Payara directly.

One thing that we'll need to be able to do is allow single applications to use HTTP instead of HTTPS, for reasons of legacy hardware compatibility. Say we have 10 applications on a server, all with their own /subdirectory after the main server URL; nine of them would be using the normal HTTPS, but one of them would need to have all traffic forced over to plain HTTP if the user tries to access it with a `https://` URL, and just allow it straight through if they start with a `http://` URL. Conversely, the other nine applications would need to do the opposite.

Right now I can do this easily with a couple of `hosts.conf` rules in Apache, can this be done simply in Payara?